# Is there a monadic version of Arbitrary to use with QuickCheck?

Tags: testing, haskell, functional-programming, monads, quickcheck

When I want to test pure code using `QuickCheck` I often have to write an `Arbitrary` instance. To test monadic code, I can use `Test.QuickCheck.Monadic` as described in this [article](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/QuickCheckST.ps).

**My question is**: Is there some canonical way to generate data that depends on a monadic context? In particular, is there some monadic version of Arbitrary? How would you go about generating data that requires a monadic context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Randomly generate a context

Just generate an appropriate random monadic context. If you are running tests, you can't stay in pure imaginary monad land, you actually have to pick a particular monad to test out. Did you pick a list monad? Randomly generate a list as the context. A state monad? Randomly generate a value of the state type for the context. Writer? Randomly generate a log.

## Randomly generate an action

So what do you want to generate, exactly? If it is a monadic action, then you need to provide a way of generating monadic actions *for your particular monad, based on its unique primitives*. e.g. randomly generated State actions should be constructed randomly from State primitives `get` and `put`.

## Put them together

If you use QuickCheck's capabilities to generate a function `f`that produces a monadic action, and use QuickCheck to generate a context `c`, then you can simply `c >>= f` to put them together. Or you can simply generate the action `a` directly, and do `c >> a`.

Answer (score 6):

`Gen` is basically what you use to work with `Arbitrary` instances in a monad framework, since the `Arbitrary` type class is basically just a provider of `Gen a` generators.